# React Context dependency cycle eslint error import/no-cycle

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-context, circular-dependency

I have a two components FirstUIProvider(Parent) and DesktopOverlay(Child) and I want to export a context from Parent to Child but this causes circular dependency which I'm unable to solve.

**CustomUIProvider**

```
export default function CustomUIProvider() {

  if (condition1) {
    return <FirstUIProvider />;
  }

  return null;
}
```

**FirstUIProvider**

```
//Dependency cycle detected
import DesktopOverlay from "components/custom-ui/DesktopOverlay";

const FirstUIContext = createContext({} as FirstUIContextType);

  const useFirstUI = () => {
    const context = useContext(FirstUIContext);

    if (!context) {
      throw new Error("useFirstUI must be used within an 
      FirstUIProvider");
    }

  return context;
};

const FirstUIProvider= () => {


  return (
    <FirstUIContext.Provider
      value={{
        value1,
        value2,
        value3,
      }}
    >
      <Grid>
        <DesktopOverlay/>
      </Grid>

    </FirstUIContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { FirstUIProvider, useFirstUI};
```

**DesktopOverlay**

```
//Dependency cycle via 
import { useFirstUI } from "components/custom-ui/providers/FirstUIProvider";

export default function DesktopOverlay() {

  const { value1, value2, value3} = useFirstUI();

  return (
    <Component1 />
    <Component 2/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to not explicitly define children of Context Provider. Usually you define it like this:

```
const FirstUIProvider = ({ children }) => {


  return (
    <FirstUIContext.Provider
      value={{
        value1,
        value2,
        value3,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </FirstUIContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and then have some Desktop component in separate file:

```
export const Desktop = () => {

  return (
    <FirstUIProvider>
      <Grid>
        <DesktopOverlay />
      </Grid>
    </FirstUIProvider>
  );
}
```

In this case you don't need to import any UI component in `FirstUIProvider` and you won't have circular dependency